# Using heavy cream vs whole milk

Tags: substitutions

Can I substitute heavy cream for milk. I am making crepes for manicotti and am wondering if they would be fluffier.

Comment: This is similar to my question [here](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/58793/how-to-thin-half-and-half-to-substitute-for-milk).

Comment: Using heavy cream will certainly make it *richer*. I would not expect it to make anything *fluffier*.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the type of milk you use would contribute too much to the fluffiness. The eggs in the crepes is what makes them fluffy in my opinion, the more eggs you add the fluffier the crepe. To make a lump-free batter, mix it in a blender till smooth.

Let batter rest for 20 or 30 minutes in the fridge to relax the gluten in the flour.  You should have fluffy crepes, just remember the more eggs you add, the more flour you will need, and don't make the batter too thick, it should be about the consistency of stirred yogurt.